# Create WooCommerce new order with specific ID

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order

I have a possibility to clone orders for each product. But I need to make a custom order ID with parent ID and add some number or letters for it. Depends, from quantity of cloning numbers in parent order.

Here is an example:

[image]

If I clone element from `#1092` it should create a new order with `#1092-1`. The second cloning will create an `#1092-2` etc.

Here is the small part of code:

```
function create_order( $original_order_id, ...
    try {
            $new_order = new WC_Order( ??? );
            $new_order->set_props( array( ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. You can add meta for original and cloned order. Just add +1 for it, each time when you will clone items.

```
function create_order( $original_order_id, ...
    try {
            $new_order = new WC_Order();
            $new_order->set_props( array( ...
    }

    $original_order = wc_get_order( $original_order_id );
    $order_item_num = $original_order->get_meta('_order_items_num');
    if($order_item_num >= 1) {
        $new_order->update_meta_data( '_order_item_num', $order_item_num+1 );
        $new_order->save();
        $original_order->update_meta_data( '_order_items_num', $order_item_num+1 );
        $original_order->save();
    } else {
        $new_order->update_meta_data( '_order_item_num', '1' );
        $new_order->save();
        $original_order->update_meta_data( '_order_items_num', '1' );
        $original_order->save();
    }
```

Now you can modify order number

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2);
function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    $parent_id = $order->parent_id;
    if($parent_id != 0) {
        $parent_order = wc_get_order( $parent_id );
        $order_sub_num = $order->get_meta('_order_item_num');
        return $parent_id . '-' . $order_sub_num;
    }
    return $order->id;
}
```